# Non blocking Scala Future over a Java Future

Tags: java, scala, listener, future

I am a newbie to Scala and Scala Futures

I have a Handle interface that implements a Java future and has a listener to it

```
public interface Handle<T> extends java.util.concurrent.Future<T> {

  void addListener(Listener<T> l);

  static interface Listener<T> {

    void success(Handle<T> handle, T output);
    void error(Handle<T> handle, Throwable t);
  }
}
```

I have a Scala API that returns this Handle. I want to make this call non-blocking

```
def test(): Handle[T] {

   // I have a method here that returns a Handle
   val handle = call()
   handle
}
```

I am thinking about how I can use scala.concurrent.Promise with the help of the Listener to make the process happen separately so that it is non-blocking

Currently, I am doing it this way

```
def test(): Future[T] {

   val p = Promise[T]
   val handle = call().addListener(new Listener[T] {

      override def success(handle: Handle[T], result: T) = p.success(result)
      override def error(handle: Handle[T], t: Throwable) = p.failure(t)
   }

 p.future
}
```

Comment: What is blocking? The `call` method blocks and returns a `Future`? That's odd. Can you show us the implementation of `call`?

Comment: The `call` method is basically a call to a Java API with the signature `<T>Handle<T> call()`

Comment: I have updated the question with my approach

Comment: What are the issues you are encountering with your approach?  Or are you simply asking whether using Promises is a good way to glue together Java and Scala Futures?